# Order of rows/columns with pull/push/offset in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question is for Twitter Bootstrap 3. I have three columns whose order and size I want to be different depending on the screen size.

On `md`:

```
----------------
|1   |2   |3   |
----------------
```

On `sm`:

```
----------------
|1      |3     |
----------------
|2             |
----------------
```

I think I should play around with pulls/pushes with the second and third `col` elements but I can't get it right yet...

I know this doesn't work, but so far it looks like...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How does this look?  [Live view](http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/tmHnx)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6  col-md-4 col-md-push-4 form-group">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 form-group">
    2
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to work :D ! Thanks! I think I was thinking md then sm, instead of the other way around. Anyway, it works :)