# Bootstrap Push/Pull Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap, and am having issues getting the alignment of elements to change right using `push` and `pull`. Here is the desired result for small screen sizes (`xs` and above):

```
-------------------
|     Search      |
-------------------
|    Directory    |
-------------------
|   Preferences   |
-------------------
```

Then for all screens sized `md` and above, I want this layout:

```
-------------------
|  Search  | Pref.|
-------------------
|    Directory    |
-------------------
```

I've read that Bootstrap layouts should be designed mobile-first, so my code is as follows:

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
}
.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
.c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 a">Search</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 b col-md-push-12">Directory</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 c col-md-pull-7">Preferences</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pMNvBOC6a3) with my code. It works as expected for the small screens, with each `div` stacked in the correct order, but I can't figure out why `push` and `pull` are just moving elements left and right, not joining them as I thought they would (even when I mess with the number of columns to push/pull). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542429/order-of-rows-columns-with-pull-push-offset-in-bootstrap#answer-24542973

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been mentioned, right now, there is no way to do this using only bootstrap classes. `push`, `pull` and `offset` will only shift elements horizontally, not vertically.

However, If you are targeting browsers that have support for it, you can use a combination of flexbox and media queries to achieve this re-ordering without needing to duplicate content.

Support breakdown: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

First, remove your push and pull classes and wrap your columns in a div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flexBox">
      <div class="a col-xs-12 col-md-7">Search</div>
      <div class="b col-xs-12 ">Directory</div>
      <div class="c col-xs-12 col-md-5">Preferences</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, use some CSS rules to set up the display of the wrapper div.

```
.flexBox
{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Lastly, set up a media query which will re-order the elements once the width is above the xs breakpoint (768px)

```
@media all and ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .flexBox .a { order:1; }
    .flexBox .b { order:3; }
    .flexBox .c { order:2; }
}
```

Full example below.

```css
.a { background-color:green; }
.b { background-color:blue; }
.c { background-color:red; }

.flexBox {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

@media all and ( min-width: 768px ) {
  .flexBox .a { order:1; }
  .flexBox .b { order:3; }
  .flexBox .c { order:2; }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flexBox">
      <div class="a col-xs-12 col-md-7">Search</div>
      <div class="b col-xs-12 ">Directory</div>
      <div class="c col-xs-12 col-md-5">Preferences</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that flexbox is a [working draft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium#Working_Draft_.28WD.29), which basically means limited browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: works perfectly; not sure if the browsers i'm writing for will support it, but an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

this can become very confusing... just make a separate div for phone screens if you are reordering the  structure on different screens.  Use the hidden-(screen-size) in Bootstrap 3.  The bootstrap push and pull works horizontally but not vertical realignment (that I know of).  Hopefully this is correct below.. I have been using other things now for this and it has been a while.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hidden-sm row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 a">Search</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 b">Directory</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 c">Preferences</div>
  </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 a">Search</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 c">Preferences</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 b">Directory</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point. I don't think you'll be able to accomplish reordering the structure any other way. For reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: yeah, looks like that would work. ideally i wouldn't have to duplicate code like that but i'm starting to think push and pull might not help me...

Answer (score 0):

Instead using the push and pull, i used hidden and visible. Hope the code below helps.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 a">Search</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 visible-md visible-lg c">Preferences</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 b">Directory</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg c">Preferences</div>
  </div>
```